# Inconsistent HttpUrlConnection behaviours on Android - how to debug?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, bad-request

I have a weird problem:
Implementing an interface to a webserver in my Android App, I connect to it using a HttpsUrlConnection. The connection uses additional HTTP Basic authorization (using `setRequestProperty`), but otherwise is a plain GET request over HTTPS.

It works perfectly fine using it on the emulator using Android 4.0.3, but fails with a "Bad request" HTTP 400 Error on Android 2.3.5 (both emulator and real device).
I do not have control over the server, so I cannot see what the problem exactly is.

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem or knows how to print/log the request that actually is being sent?

TIA,

Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set up a proxy such as Fiddler or Charles proxy (and I think there are firefox extensions as well) and point your app to the proxy instead. Even if you don't set it up to actually be a proxy (such that the requests actually work), as long as it captures the requests you should be able to compare the difference between the requests made from 4.0.3 vs. 2.3.5.

Comment: Thank you very much - Charles works perfectly on my Mac and I discovered that Android 2.3.5 does not automatically set the "Host" parameter in the HTTP Request, while Android 4 does.
But at least I know now, where the problem is! Thank you